# CWE 201: fetch function

Tags: security, veracode, secure-coding

Veracode scan is showing a low level vulnerability in the fetch function. What's the best way to fix this?

```
const response = await fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
```

Comment: Does Veracode provide any information about the vulnerability?  If all the tool says is that a problem exists, but doesn't have any information about the problem or why it thinks it's a problem in the first place then I wouldn't consider that a particularly useful tool.

Comment: Veracode should be giving you a data flow for how it considers the vulnerability to be triggered. CWE-201 shouldn't be just triggering on the code you give - it will either be that the variable `url` is able to be exploited, or (probably more likely) that `fetch` leaks something else. You should be able to follow back the variable to where it is constructed, or drill down into the function to see what it leaks, depending on what is being considered here.

Comment: Veracode gave 'fetch' as the attack vector. And a few references to the articles regarding CWE 201:    The application calls the fetch() function, which will result in data being transferred out of the application (via the network or another medium). In this case, the message being sent appears to be considered private; this may include credentials such as usernames or passwords, data normally stored in cryptographically-protected vaults such as keychains, or other private information. @ricardkelly

Comment: @vbgp: The (albeit incomplete) code shown isn't sending *any* data.  Maybe `url` contains values which may be sensitive?  Maybe it's sending values to a 3rd party URL?  Maybe after the `headers` object there is other data being sent which may be sensitive?  Maybe it's a false positive?  We don't know.  But for the question being asked, there's nothing *inherently* insecure about the mere act of just *using `fetch`*.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments everyone. It is a false positive. There is no sensitive data being sent through the 'url' variable.